# Register JS files at the end of the body tag in the Control Panel

Tags: templating, craft3, includejs

I would like to add my own external JS sources at the very end of the body tag in the Craft control panel.

I've already tried using:

```
{% do view.registerJsFile("<CDN_URL>", {position:3}) %}
```

according to https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-view#registerJsFile()-detail, but Craft is always adding its own JS sources after mine.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the CP asset as depency then it will be loaded after it

```twig
{% do view.registerJsFile("<CDN_URL>",{
    depends: 'craft\\web\\assets\\cp\\CpAsset',
    position:3
}) %}
```

That's because Yii2 will always register Bundles without any dependencies first / in the order they are defined. If you require the `CpAsset` it will be loaded afterwards